# SQL Server : Join If Between

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables:

- **Query1**: contains 3 columns, `Due_Date`, `Received_Date`, `Diff`
  where `Diff` is the difference in the two dates in days
- **QueryHol** with 2 columns, `Date`, `Count`

This has a list of dates and the count is set to 1 for everything. All these dates represent public holidays.

I want to be able to get the sum of QueryHol["Count"] if QueryHol["Date"] is between Query1["Due_Date"] and Query1["Received_Date"]

Result Wanted: a column joined onto Query1 to state how many public holidays fell into the date range so they can be subtracted from the Query1["Diff"] column to give a reflection of working days.

[image]

[image]

Because the 01-01-19 is a bank holiday i would want to minus that from the Diff to end up with results like below

[image]

Let me know if you require any more info.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by formatted text?

Comment: Text that is copied and pasted into your question and then formatted as code. We can't do anything with images. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons you should not use images to post code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option:

```
SELECT query1.due_date
, query1.received_date
, query1.diff
, queryhol.count
, COALESCE(query1.diff - queryhol.count, query1.diff) as DiffCount

FROM Query1

OUTER APPLY(
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
 FROM QueryHol
  WHERE QueryHol.Date <= Query1.Received_Date
  AND QueryHol.Date >= Query1.Due_Date
) AS queryhol
```

You may need to play around with the join condition - as it is assumes that the `Received_Date` is always later than the `Due_Date` which there is not enough data to know all of the use cases.

Comment: Hi Cole, This works perfectly. Was abe to adapt for more calculations as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, I think this is a possible solution:

```
select due_date,
       receive_date,
       diff,
       (select sum(table2.count)
          from table2
         where table2.due_date between table1.due_date and table1.due_date) sum_holi,
       table1.diff - (select sum(table2.count)
          from table2
         where table2.date between table1.due_date and table2.due_date) diff_holi
  from table1
 where [...] --here your conditions over table1.
```

Comment: Hi Nokin, i get the error of Table2.count can not be bound?

Comment: sorry there are 2 mistakes in the example: First subselect "...where table2.due_date..", the correct is "...where table2.date..";. Second subselect "...and table2.due_date..", the correct is "...and table1.due_date...".
If you need more help, please put your query.